# How to consider binary variable in addition to sequence?

Tags: python, keras, sequence

I want to add a binary variable (**x2**) to each sample to predict **y**. So:  **x1 + x2 = y**

**x1** is a **sequence of vectors** (a document composed of a sequence-of-sentences) and **x2** is just a **binary** variable. **y** is also **binary**.

Until now, I just consider **x1** to predict **y** using `keras`:

```
input  = Input(shape=(sentences_per_doc, maximum_sequence_length))
lstm_out = Bidirectional(LSTM(50, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True))(input  )
sent_dense = Dense(100, activation='relu', name='sent_dense')(lstm_out) 
sent_drop = Dropout(0.5,name='sent_dropout')(sent_dense)
prediction = Dense(1, activation='softmax',name='output')(sent_drop)
```

But since the input to my model is a vector-sequence, how do I add **binary** variable **x2** to my model to predict y?

I considered adding the binary variable at the end of each **sequence-vector** (e.g. `seq_vec=[1,2,3] + binary_x2_i=[1] = new_seq=[1,2,3,1]`) but I dont know if this makes sense.. cause each sample *i* then contains *binary_x2_i*

`sample_i = [[1,2,3,1],[4,5,6,1],[7,8,9,1]]`

Comment: The question is, what is exactly your purpose with that addition and what that binary variable represents?

Comment: Say the document (x1) is a patient-report. I read the report to see if I can ifer from the report that the patient got healthy (y). (Say good report x1 -> Patient got healthy y=1). Now, I also try to consider other variables (x2). x2 e.g. if the patient got a certain treatment (x2=1 he did, x2=0 he didnt).. or x2 if he saw the nurse, or didnt. - With the documents being encoded as a document vector (instead of being composed of a sequence), I was told, I can just add another variable to the vector to represent x2; (and then run a logistic regression).. but with sequences idk

Comment: I think, your output will not be good with softmax and a single neuron.

Comment: What do you recommend? Do you think, I should one-hot-encode the binary ```y``` vector (```[1,0]```, ```[0,1]```) and set the last layer to ```Dense(2)```?  Actually, I have an Attention-layer after the LSTM https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59791292/lstm-attention-layer-network-dimensions-for-classification-task

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description theoritically can be important, where the additional `x2` feature, saying better, its value occured. So you should add that feature inside any sequence represented by an additional value.

If the values in the sequences, which mapped different treatments were discribed with **(0,1,2..n)** values then the **n + 1** value will represent the extra feature.
In addition you have to increase the `maximum_sequence_length` by **1** to reserve the place to for the extra feature.

Thus at the end your your samples should look e.g. like this:

```
sample_i = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6,10],[7,8,9]]
```

if the extra features happened in the time of the 2nd sequence.